# Bar released from upright position rotates about a lower hinge before being caught by a steel cable, how to calculate the tension on the cable?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation, potential-energy

I wish to check the safety factor of a steel cable that I've designed to catch a heavy bar that rotates freely due to the gravitational force acting on it.

From the upright position, I'm assuming that the bar has a rotational velocity of 0rad/s before rotating about a lower hinge (hence, gaining rotational kinetic energy), and comes to a stop when the cable goes from slack (sagging cable) to taut (straight - full length).

I've currently modelled the cable as a spring where the rotational kinetic energy is converted to elastic potential energy within the cable upon a small extension. This may be where I've made a mistake since cables don't alway follow Hooke's law and the elastic extension I've found doesn't seem to account for the momentum. Based on this, I'm guessing that I've gone about this problem the wrong way. I'll attach my working with some example numbers below.

Any help or guidance on this will be hugely appreciated!

[image: Page 1 of Working]

[image: Page 2 of Working]

Comment: I feel this question may be better suited to engineering or even home improvement. The reason is that steel cables of typical widths are very, very able to withstand great forces. If this is indeed a real construction, I'd bet the thing you'd have to be more wary about is how you have installed the other end of the wire on the wall. I can easily imagine your heavy bar tearing down a wall part rather than snapping a steel cable in half.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The cable will exert an impulse which changes the bar's angular momentum. The maximum force will depend on how much the cable can stretch.  Treating it like a spring (with a high k) is not unreasonable (but measuring the k could be a problem), and there is likely to some bounce.